# Validation Function for URL in plugin

Tags: plugins, metabox, validation

```
    if ( cpmb_is_valid_mp3( $_FILES['video-url']['name'] ) ) {

            $response = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['video-url']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['video-url']['tmp_name'] ) );

            if ( 0 == strlen ( trim( $response['error'] ) ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mp3', $response['url'] );
            }

        // Otherwise, mark this as an invalid file
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mp3', 'invalid-file-type' );
        }
```

The above is a part of code from a ***plugin***. Then here comes the ***function*** →

```
function cpmb_is_valid_mp3( $filename ) {

    $path_parts = pathinfo( $filename );
    return 'mp3' == strtolower( $path_parts['extension'] );

}
```

Let me tell you what I ***understand***:
If it is validated that file is `.mp3` then execute the code?

***QUESTION***: Can someone help me to create such validations for a "URL"?

I have tried like this →

```
if ( cpmb_is_valid_url( $_REQUEST['video-url']['name'] ) ) {

   Some code is executed here.

}
```

But I have no idea how to write this function →

```
cpmb_is_valid_url
```

Comment: what part of the url are you trying to validate/confirm exists? Or are you trying to confirm it is a url at all? (also this will probably fall under a general php type question, fyi)

Comment: Input by the admin/author of the post in the metabox such youtube, vimeo URL.

Comment: should I paste the code for MP3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and/or [`filter_var()` with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). `parse_url()` gives you a bit more control. Combine that with a sanitization as mentioned at the end.

Here are couple use cases that will hopefully give you a better idea on how to proceed:

---

**If you want to verify that the url's domain is of an approved site:**

```
function url_allowed( $url ) {

        $allowed_hosts = array(
                        'youtube.com',
                        'vimeo.com'
                        ); 
        if ( in_array( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ), $allowed_hosts ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;      
    }
```

Then pass it the url to check within your conditional:

```
if ( url_allowed( $value_of_url_to_check_wherever_you_are_getting_it ) ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

---

**If you just want to confirm it is a url at all** (which will include `ftp://`, etc., btw),

```
if ( filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

---

**If you would like to only allow urls beginning with `http` or `https`**,

```
if ( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME ) == 'http' || parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME ) == 'https' ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

---

I would also recommended sanitizing the url either via the WordPress [`esc_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs) or php's [`filter_var( $url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL )`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_url.asp)

---

### Edit: Using WP's `wp_parse_url()`

WordPress provides a wrapper for PHP's `parse_url()`: [`wp_parse_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_url/). It returns an array of `'scheme'`, `'host'`, and `'path'`. Usage is the same as above:

```
function url_allowed( $url ) {

        $allowed_hosts = array(
                        'youtube.com',
                        'vimeo.com'
                        );
        $url_array = wp_parse_url($url); 
        if ( in_array( $url_array['host'], $allowed_hosts ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;      
    }
```

---

Additionally, the WordPress function [`wp_allowed_protocols()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_allowed_protocols/) returns a default list of protocols you could check against:

```
  array( 'http', 
         'https', 
         'ftp', 
         'ftps', 
         'mailto', 
         'news', 
         'irc', 
         'gopher', 
         'nntp', 
         'feed', 
         'telnet', 
         'mms', 
         'rtsp', 
         'svn', 
         'tel', 
         'fax', 
         'xmpp', 
         'webcal', 
         'urn' 
    )
```

You can filtered this list with the hook [`kses_allowed_protocols`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/kses_allowed_protocols/). 
In example, removing the `mailto` protocol may go something like this:

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', 'my_protocols' );
function my_protocols( $protocols ) {

    if( ($key = array_search( 'mailto', $protocols ) ) !== false ) {    
        unset( $protocols[ $key ] );
    }
}
```

Do note that this approved protocol list is used by [`_links_add_base()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_links_add_base/), [`edit_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/edit_user/) (for the user url field), [`wp_kses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/), [`wp_kses_one_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_one_attr/), and [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/).

I would contend it is better to explicitly check the intended protocol of the input field rather than just checking it against this array.

---

### A more complete usage case

Since your usage is to allow users to input urls from specific sites, and in both cases these video urls are served using protocol `https`, I would check for the site `host` and force the protocol, and use `esc_url()` to clean up characters.

Since the end result will require you to know whether the url is from Vimeo or YouTube, you could save that as well.

**check against allowed hosts, used by** `url_verify()`

```
function url_allowed_host( $host ) {

    $allowed_hosts = array(
                    'youtube.com',
                    'vimeo.com'
                    );

    if ( in_array( $host, $allowed_hosts ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;      
}
```

**parse entered url, force https, verify allowed host, create and return array of values**

```
   function url_verify( $url ) {

        $url_array = wp_parse_url( $url );

        if ( $url_array['scheme'] !== 'https' ) {

            $url_array['scheme'] = 'https';
        }

        if ( url_allowed_host( $url_array['host'] ) ) {

            //lets ditch the .com
            $host_word = explode( '.', $url_array['host'] );

            //this should now be just "youtube" or "vimeo"
            $meta_array['host'] = $host_word;
            $meta_array['url']  = $url_array['scheme'] . $url_array['host'] . $url_array['path'];

            return $meta_array;

       } else {

        return false;

       }

   }
```

**Save the array with url and url host name**

```
  add_action( 'save_post', 'my_meta_save', 10, 2 );

  function my_meta_save( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
        }
    //do nonce check here

    //assuming form field is named: video-url, make sure it is set and not empty AND that url_verify did not return false
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['video-url'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['video-url'] ) ) && ( false !== url_verify( $_POST['video-url'] ) ) ) {


        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'video_url', esc_url( $POST['video_url'] ) );

    }
    //if any of the above are not true, treat it as blank and delete existing value
    else {

        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'video-url' );
    }    


  }
```

**Retrieve the values**

```
$video_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'video-url', false );
$url = esc_url( $video_meta['url'] );
$host = santize_text_field( $video_meta['host'] );
```

**Displaying something conditionally per host**

I use a switch here in case you have a longer list of allowed domains.

```
switch ( $host ) {
    case "youtube":
        //do some youtube stuff
        break;

    case "vimeo":
        //do some vimeo stuff
        break;
}
```

Comment: I have a question since you have restricted the url only from youtube and Vimeo so I think just validating if it is a URL is enough Isn't it? secondly, you have given a wonderful solution aren't we using core php functions whereas WordPress functions can be used there?

Comment: as far as validation of user input goes, I would be as specific to the expected entry as you can. If the end result can only handle certain sources (i.e. youtube, vimeo, etc.) I would force their usage. Same with http or https.  I am unaware of any wordpress function(s) that perform url parsing, even as wrappers for `parse_url()`, but they may exist. You can definitely handle sanitization via WP's `esc_url()`.

Comment: sir, I need a little more favor from you. can you also help me in writing `//do stuff` especially then the part that I have outlined in the red-box → https://www.screencast.com/t/su9ivuUOU I am building it from by seeing a plugin that has done this for mp3.

Comment: that bit would part of a `save_meta_boxes()` type function that is hooked to `save_post` for saving the values of the meta box's form fields when the post is saved/update. Swap their use of `$_FILES` for `$_POST` and it will look more familiar.

Comment: can I use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391188/url-analogue-of-files)

Comment: the data from the form fields will be present in $_POST upon submitting the form. You're posting that data to the server, so in the interests of disambiguation I would use $_POST here.